# returning array and message to function

Tags: php

please help me out regarding this function.  I want to fetch data from the database and if there are results, I want to return a message and data array.

```
    $this->query=("select * from user where pno='".$search."'");
    $rd = $this->executeQuery();
    $data = $rd->fetch_assoc();


    if ($data) {
        $message = "Record found.";
    } else {
        $message = "Record not found.";
    }
return array($data, $message);
```

I am calling it this way:

```
list($data, $message)=$user->search($result);

echo $message
echo $data['name'];
```

I am getting the message but I am unable to fetch the array.
Please help me out if there is a problem in the function or if I can improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re missing a semicolon after `echo $message` in your code example.

Try appending this to your code and tell us what it returns:

```
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: in the function its show record array while from the calling point its Null

Answer (score 2):

**Never** do it this way
you should put your message setting code **outside** of the function.

```
function getData(){
    $this->query=("select * from user where pno='".$search."'");
    $rd = $this->executeQuery();
    return $rd->fetch_assoc();
}
if ($data = getData()){
  $message = "Record found.";
  echo $message;
  echo $data['name'];
} else {
  $message = "Record not found.";
  echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're using, but most likely you'll have an array of rows in $data, even if there is only single row. Try `$data[0]['name']`. Besides, I'd suggest that you move that message from your function to the place where it's called, and make the function return NULL or FALSE if nothing found.

```
$this->query=("select * from user where pno='".$search."'");
$rd = $this->executeQuery();
$data = $rd->fetch_assoc();

return empty($data)?FALSE:$data;
```